# How to write a JUnit 5 test case for controller method using Spring-boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito, junit5

I have looked at a few tutorials, and am not quite sure how to proceed with writing a test case for my controller method using JUnit 5.  I have read up on TestRestTemplate and Mock functions, but still feel at a loss as to how to begin.  I am using a MySQL database, the application contains two classes Product and Feedback, it has a OneToMany relationship, with the owning entity being Feedback.

How do I write a test for the method below?

```
    @PostMapping("/view/{id}")
    public ModelAndView addReview(@PathVariable("id") int id, @RequestParam("review") String review, HttpServletRequest request) {
        Product product = dao.findById(id).get();
        Feedback feedback = new Feedback(review);
        product.getFeedbacks().add(feedback);
        feedback.setProduct(product);
        dao.save(product);
        List<Feedback> fs = product.getFeedbacks();
        Collections.sort(fs, new FeedbackComparator());
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("fs", fs);
        return new ModelAndView("/view").addObject("product", product);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to write a test for your Spring MVC controller endpoints:

1. Use `@WebMvcTest` and `MockMvc` to test *only* your web-layer in isolation.

For such tests, you usually mock all collaborators (in your case your dao) of your controller. Using `MockMvc` you can then fire requests against a mocked Servlet environment that Spring Boot creates for you. This way you can ensure e.g. your controller endpoints are properly protected (by Spring Security), your path variables and query parameters are mapped as expected, you're returning the correct HTTP response and headers, your `Model` contains the default attributes, etc.

You can find further information on how to write tests with `MockMvc` as part of [this guide](https://rieckpil.de/guide-to-testing-spring-boot-applications-with-mockmvc/).

2. Use `@SpringBootTest` to populate your whole application context, start the real Servlet container (e.g. Tomcat) and invoke your endpoints with the `TestRestTemplate` or the `WebTestClient` over HTTP.

This setup requires all your external infrastructure components (database, messaging queues, external systems, etc.) to be available during test execution. This usually takes quite some time and such tests are not as fast as the first variant. [Testcontainers](https://rieckpil.de/howto-write-spring-boot-integration-tests-with-a-real-database/) can help you a lot here. This way you can ensure the whole use case is working as expected and write integration tests for your application.

So as a general recommendation you should have both kinds of tests and at least ensure your important happy-paths are working as expected with an integration test. For more *low-level* checks for your controller, the `@WebMvcTest` annotation comes quite handy.